# Authorization with API key and password for request-promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, request-promise

I am trying to make a GET call to the shopify api with request-promise in node.
I keep getting this error :-

> '401 - {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access ' +
>       'token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"}'

How should format the options to take an API key and password?

```
const request = require("request-promise");
const Parse = require('parse/node');


const options = {
  method:'GET',
  json: true,
  uri: 'https://the-bib-wine-company.myshopify.com/admin/api/2019-07/orders.json',
  headers: {
   'Authorization': <api key and password encode64>
  }
}


request(options)
  .then(function(response) {

var Test = Parse.Object.extend("Test");
    var test = new Test();

test.set('orders', 'success');
    test.save();

  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

Comment: Did you miss step 3? "Prepend the base64-encoded string with Basic and a space" sot that `'Authorization': '<api key and password encode64>'` becomes `'Authorization': 'Basic <api key and password encode64>'`

Comment: I will try this as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered my own question, if it helps anyone.

`auth: {
        'user': 'API key',
        'pass': 'mypassword'
      }`

Answer (score 0):

YOUR_STORE_ID will be in your url & it has numbers this is not your store name or site name.

ACCESS_TOKEN you can get by going to your apps and creating and clicking develop app, be sure to select your permissions and specify api

```
import requests
        
        # Define the API endpoint
        url = 'https://YOUR_STORE_ID.myshopify.com/admin/api/2024-01/orders.json?status=any'
        
        
        # Replace 'ACCESS_TOKEN' with your actual Shopify access token
        headers = {
            'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'my_token_here',
        }
        
        
        # Make the GET request
        response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        
        
        # Check if the request was successful
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Convert the response to JSON
            data = response.json()
            # Print the response
            print(data)
        else:
            # Print the error
            print(f'Failed to retrieve data: {response.status_code} - {response.text}')
```